# how do I get zsh to *just* list the stuff in my current directory during tab completion?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In zsh when I type a few characters it lists all this stuff (commands and I think subfiles).
How do I get zsh to *just* list the contents of my current_directory?

[image]

In the picture above I type the character `a` in the hope that it will let me tab complete to `a_dir`,
but it offers me a whole catalogue of commands.

Is there a permanent command that just lets me type the character `a`?

Comment: `./a[tab]` should work.

Comment: @DopeGhoti thanks for this. Maybe there is a permanent command that allows me to just type the character `a`? I tried set `opt autocd` in `.zshrc`??

Comment: How would ZSH know when you wanted to tab complete a command versus not?

Comment: I'm new. Good point @thrig . @DopeGhoti 's suggestion shall be my new default. I wonder if there is a modal operation (perhaps a `keyboard shortcut`) to implement this behaviour?  (i.e. to tell `zsh` that I just want to change directory)

Comment: Typing `cd ` first is a good way to indicate you want to complete on directories...

Answer (score 4):

Set the `tag-order` style like so

```
zstyle :completion::complete:-command-:: tag-order local-directories -
```

The tag `local-directories` is only available when the `autocd` option is enabled. The `-` tells zsh to discard any possible matches in other `tag`s

You may find the `insert-tab` style of interest too; so when `$BUFFER` is empty, it will still complete files in the current directory.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab false
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (even if I am not sure to see the purpose of it) and to address the comments following it, there is a way to complete only by filename without loosing the normal completion. You can associate the filename completion to a key (here *Ctrl+F*):

```
zstyle ':completion:files:*' completer _files
zstyle ':completion:files:*' file-patterns '*:all\ files'
zstyle ':completion:files:*' hidden all
zle -C files menu-complete _generic
bindkey '^F' files
```

It could be useful maybe by setting *autocd* and by adding suffix aliases, for instance:

```
alias -s pdf="zathura"
alias -s jpg="sxiv -f"
alias -s tex="vim"
setopt autocd
```